# SQL Server: Copy database from linked server to local

Tags: sql-server, database, linked-server

I have a remote server (called server A) and in this remote server defined a Linked Server to another server (server B).

I have a SQL Server database on my local PC.

I want copy one of server B's databases to my local PC.

I don't have access to server B in a direct way and I can only access from that with the linked server defined in server A.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to request the Table in B and then rewrite that into your Local DB.

Save:

```
$file = 'table.sql';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$file' FROM `##table##`");
```

Load:

```
$file = 'table.sql';
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE `##table##`");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where to write the function? If i write in local DB, then i can not access to linked server in DB B, if i write function in server B, then i can not access to local db from server B

Comment: I see, that is very annoying.

Server B function = Query DB for the table, save the result into a file.

Server Local = Loop the file and INSERT into the DB.

 What's your server running? Php?

Comment: Thank you Nicolay Hekkens for your attention, but i use SQL Server. Your code is true for mysql.